# Configure pretty url iis 7.5

Tags: yii, server, information-server

I want to use pretty url on my application. I'm using Yii 1.1 (Php framework) and IIS 7.5

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

<directoryBrowse enabled="false" />

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="Hide Yii Index" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="." ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule> 
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

I have configure my IIS rewrite rule like this. But isn't work. Someone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you insert below code in web.config

```
 <serverVariables>
      <set name="REQUEST_URI" value="{UNENCODED_URL}"  replace="true" />
 </serverVariables>
```

and result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                    <serverVariables>
                        <set name="REQUEST_URI" value="{UNENCODED_URL}" replace="true" />
                    </serverVariables>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This problem occurs mostly in Persian and Arabic Language 
and mostly use in wordpress website